# Adding a node in an existing cluster of Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I made a cluster that has 2 nodes now. I want to add another node to it so that it becomes a 3 node cluster. I have read the documentation from datastax. I want to know if, when I add the 3rd node, will I have to change the token value of the previous 2 nodes and will I have to start the cluster again?
Also I want to know if, apart from basic settings (listen address,rpc address,token,seeds), I need to change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a single new node to your 2-node cluster without changing tokens, you will end up with one node owning 50% of the keys and 2 nodes owning 25% each.  Instead, when you bring your new node online, you should specify the initial token (in cassandra.yaml).  You should then use `nodetool move` to move the token on node 2, followed by `nodetool cleanup` to remove any unneeded data.

You should use the following tokens:

```
Node 1: 0 -- should already be set
Node 2: 56713727820156407428984779325531226112 -- will require the move
Node 3: 113427455640312814857969558651062452224 -- will be set using initial token
```

Comment: so does node 2 get a new token as well?

Comment: @James: Yes, the idea behind running `nodetool move` is to change the token on node 2 so it owns a third of the tokens.